# Scala most efficient operator to add to a list

Tags: scala

Building a scala list by modifying it incrementally. What is the most efficient "add" operator? In terms of CPU and resource consumption.

For example, from List(1,2,3) we want to create a list of tuples of consecutive numbers. Which gives the result: List((1,2), (2,3))

**Method 1 - using :+ operator**

```
def createConsecutiveNumPair1[T](inList: List[T]) : List[(T, T)] = {
  var listResult = List[(T, T)]()
  var prev = inList(0)
  for (curr <- inList.tail)
  {
    listResult = listResult :+ (prev, curr)
    prev = curr
  }
  listResult
}
```

**Method 2 - using ::= operator**

```
def createConsecutiveNumPair2[T](inList: List[T]) : List[(T, T)] = {
  var listResult = List[(T, T)]()
  var prev = inList(0)
  for (curr <- inList.tail)
  {
    listResult ::= (prev, curr)
    prev = curr
  }
  listResult
}
```

**TEST**

```
scala> val l1 = List(1,2,3)
l1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> createConsecutiveNumPair1(l1)
res77: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,3))

scala> createConsecutiveNumPair2(l1)
res78: List[(Int, Int)] = List((2,3), (1,2))
```

**QUESTION**: which operator has lowest CPU, resource consumption? Would also appreciate if you can suggest a better scala way to rewrite the method above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your first code is that it appends, which is `O(n)` on `List`. So the algorithm basically is `O(n^2)`.

It very efficient to prepend on `List`, because it runs in constant time `O(1)`, which you do in your second algorithm. You could use that and do a `reverse` at the end to make the result of the two methods equal, which would roughly make it it run in `O(n)`.

However there is already a nice method in the library that does what you want. `sliding` is what you are looking for. The parameter for sliding defines the size of the tuples.

This would give you a `List[List[Int]]`:

```
List(1,2,3,4).sliding(2).toList  //List(List(1,2), List(2,3), List(3,4))
```

If you insist on tuples, you can additionally use `collect` or `map`. Be aware that `map` will throw an exception when the list only has one element.

```
List(1,2,3,4).sliding(2).collect{
  case List(a,b) => (a,b)
}.toList                        //List((1,2), (2,3), (3,4))
```

Comment: Helpful for the information about `sliding` method.

Comment: @Kigyo thank you for the explanation about the complexity. Now I understand better the subtle difference in [List Scala Doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List) about these operators. Thanks for sliding. Nice to know.

Answer (score 1):

These methods often just call each other (though check the implementation to be sure). `List` is a singly-linked list, optimized for accessing the head rather than the tail, so adding elements to the front rather than the end is much more efficient. If you want to access / add elements at the end of the list, it's better to use `Vector` instead.

(As always, if you're asking the question at all you should have automated tooling to be able to tell you the answer. If you're not using a profiler that tells you which parts of your app are slow, it's not worth spending time on this kind of microoptimization - you're almost certainly optimizing the wrong part).

Comment: well said "it's not worth spending time on this kind of micro-optimization - you're almost certainly optimizing the wrong part". Unless you are dealing with a VERY large list.

Comment: @Imm, thank you for your great advices. Can you please suggest a profiling tool for Scala (and possibly which could also test Spark)?

Comment: I use JProfiler - it's expensive but very much worth it IMO. I understand it's possible to run Hadoop/yarn jobs under JProfiler which would allow you to profile spark code as well, but I don't have any direct experience of doing that.